# On my android app I can't login even I get true value from database

Tags: android, mongodb, if-statement

username and password is correct but "if(username=...)" this block not work. There is no error too. Its return 0 value to onPostExecute() method.

```
@Override
public Integer doInBackground(Void... Params){
    try{
           ....
            if(userName=="sinan" && password=="123456")
            {
                returnValue=1;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                returnValue=0;
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return (-1);
    }
}
```

asdasd

```
   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result){ 
  super.onPostExecute(result);      
  if(result==1)
    {
        txtViewUserName.setText(userName);
        txtViewPassword.setText(password);
    }
    else if(result.intValue()==0)
    {
        txtViewUserName.setText("Result 0");
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: See [how to compare strings in java](http://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/4896787)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for String comparison you have to use `equals()` method:

```
 if(userName.equals("sinan") && password.equals("123456"))
```

don´t worry, very common mistake when we to start in java programming :)

Remember:

> **.equals()** This method compares this string to the specified object. The result
>   is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a String object
>   that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

#### `==` : tests for reference equality.

#### `.equals()` : tests for value equality.

Answer (score 4):

Your Mistake Was You Were Using `==` operator,The `==` operator compares the objects location in memory

Use `equals()` method in place of `==` operator it compares the Two String Objects

```
   Override
     public Integer doInBackground(Void... Params){
         try{
       ....
        if(userName.equals("sinan") && password.equals("123456"))
        {
            returnValue=1;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            returnValue=0;
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return (-1);
}
```

}

Comment: why -1? i think this answer is correct too. :o, but must me explained.

Comment: Explained Now  My Answer